# Как вывести в консоль каждый элемент массива раз в секунду?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Добрый день подскажите пожалуйста как мне вывести каждый элемент массива раз в секунду

```
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

a.forEach(el => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(el)
  }, 1000)
})
```

данный код выводит все элементы массива разом через секунду, а мне надо чтобы он выводил по очереди каждую секунду, как это можно сделать ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

a.forEach((el, i) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(el)
  }, (i + 1) * 1000)
})
```

Comment: @Kundakchan
Если ввести еще одну переменную, то можно регулировать скорость вывода. Например так:
let sTime = 2
В коде подправить строку так:
}, (i + 1) * sTime * 1000)
В качестве примера попробовал на чистом Javascript результат - https://jsfiddle.net/Mister_X_2k/jbdgcva2/

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с интервалом:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

let i = 0;

let bubu = setInterval( function() {
  let x = arr[i++] || clearInterval( bubu );
  if( x !== undefined ) console.log( x );
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Наверно можно попробовать не выводить сразу, а при помощи цикла. Завести отдельную переменную для номера элемента массива, потом в цикле выводить этот самый элемент, а после одной секунду увеличить ту самую переменную.

Цикл, который повторяется столько раз, сколько элементов в массиве. i - та самая переменная.
В цикле выводишь объект массива номер i, ждешь секунду, увеличиваешь i. Как-то так

Comment: это было бы так в любом языке, где можно синхронно подождать , в js это противоречит подходу